# limiting file output to only 2 lines

Tags: bash

I ping a series of addresses and append the latency results to a file (each address has a separate file). I'm trying to limit the file to only contain the last 2 entries.

```
$outpath=/opt/blah/file.txt
resp_str="0.42"
echo $resp_str >> $outpath

tail -2 $outpath > $outpath
```

Without tail, the file continues to grow with the new data (simply .42 for this example). But when I call tail, it writes out an empty file. If I redirect the tail output to a file of a different name, then I get the expected result. Can I not write out to a file as I read it? Is there a simple solution?

Here's the complete script:

```
OUT_PATH=/opt/blah/sites/
TEST_FILE=/opt/blah/test.txt

while IFS=, read -r ip name; do
    if [[ "$ip" != \#* ]]; then
        RESP_STR=$( ping -c 1 -q $ip | grep rtt| awk '{print $4}' | awk -F/ '{ print $2; }')
        echo $RESP_STR >> "$OUT_PATH""test/"$name".txt"
    fi
done << $TEST_FILE
```

Comment: what do you mean *'file continues to grow'*? what (command) is writing to the file?

Comment: Echo is writing to the file. This script would be called every 5 minutes. I've just simplified the script for example purposes. resp_str is actually a parsed response from ping.

Comment: but if the script is called every 5 minutes, isn't the file going to continue to grow? or is the intent to insure the file only ever contains a max of 2 lines (ie, the 2 latest `ping` results)

Comment: That's why I'm trying to use tail, to capture the last two entries and overwrite the file so that it doesn't grow.

Comment: @pjh possibly. If I'm understanding it correctly, I'd have to write to a temp file first then back.

Comment: Also see [Bash Pitfalls #13 (cat file | sed s/foo/bar/ > file)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cat_file_.7C_sed_s.2Ffoo.2Fbar.2F_.3E_file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `tail -2 $outpath > $outpath`

`>` truncates the file before `tail` starts reading it.

You need to buffer the output of `tail` before writing it back to that file. Use [sponge](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sponge) to achieve this:

```sh
tail -2 $outpath | sponge $outpath
```

Comment: For those reading this in the future, sponge is part of the moreutils package (which I had to install). Very useful command!

Answer (score 0):

You can use pipe `|` to send the output of one commande to another, in this case **tail**.
We can then append out to a file using `>>`.  If we use `>` we overwrite the file each time and all previous content is lost.
This example writes the 2 last files in the directory to *log.txt* each time it is run.

```
ls  | tail -2 >> log.txt
```

Comment: I'm not following the purpose of using ls.

Comment: I'm just using **ls** as an example of a command that will produce more than 2 lines of output to demonstrate the principle of piping to another command and then writing to file. You can put any other command in place of **ls**.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- need to code for parallel, concurrent processes (use of temp files will require each process to have a uniquely named temp file)
- go ahead and code to support a high volume of operations (ie, reduce overhead of creating/destroying temp files)

One idea using `mktemp` to create a temporary file ... we'll wrap this in a function for easier use:

```
keep2 () {

    # Usage: keep2 filename "new line of text"

    [[ ! -f "${tmpfile}" ]] &&
    tmpfile=$(mktemp)

    tail -1 "$1" > "${tmpfile}"
    { cat "${tmpfile}"; echo "$2"; } > "$1"
}
```

**NOTES:**

- the hardcoded `-1` (`tail -1`) could be parameterized or reference a user-defined env variable
- OP can change the order of the input parameters as desired

Taking for a test drive;

```
> logfile

for ((i=1;i<=5;i++))
do
    echo "######### $i"
    keep2 logfile "$i"
    cat logfile
done
```

This generates:

```
######### 1
1
######### 2
1
2
######### 3
2
3
######### 4
3
4
######### 5
4
5
```

---

In OP's code the following line:

```
echo $RESP_STR >> "$OUT_PATH""test/"$name".txt"
```

would be replaced with:

```
keep2 "$OUT_PATH""test/"$name".txt" "${RESP_STR}"
```